# How to sort View items

Tags: python, qt, model, header, pyqt

Setting an `setSortingEnabled()` to `True` makes it possible to click the column header name to sort the view's items:

```
tableView=QTableView()
tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)
```

But even while the attribute has been set the view will display the items unsorted.
In order to sort the items the header must be clicked.
Question: How to make view go ahead and to sort its items before the header is clicked.
So the view is sorted straight from the start.

Comment: Thanks for the link! There is probably a method called when a header gets clicked. If so can this method to be called programmatically?

Comment: Looks like we can get QTableView header object by calling `headerObj=tableView.horizontalHeader()`

Comment: According to docs headerObj's `.sortIndicatorChanged()` method suspiciously close to what we want. Is it possible to trigger it programmatically?

Comment: While I can link the header to any method with: `self.connect(taskViewHeader, SIGNAL('sortIndicatorChanged(int, Qt::SortOrder)'), self.sortChanged)` I was not able to emit `'sortIndicatorChanged` signal programmatically...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`QHeaderView.setSortIndicator(logicalIndex, order)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#setSortIndicator)

For your example, this would mean calling `tableView.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicator(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)` to sort the first column in ascending order.

Note that you are passing in `logicalIndex` which may not correspond to the visualIndex if the columns have been reordered. `QHeaderView` provides methods for translating between the two if you need it (but I think it is unlikely you will need it).

Comment: Terrific! Thanks! Now we have two ways to do the same!

Comment: @Sputnix Yes, I wasn't aware of the tableview specific method you answered with. The method in in my answer should be applicable to all types of view though (like a treeview) with an appropriate change of `view.horizontalHeader()` to `view.header()`

Answer (score 1):

To sort `QTableView()` without clicking on its header (assuming the `tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)` was set) use:

```
tableView.sortByColumn(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
```